# Smallest range of substring in string

Tags: python, string, range, substring

I have a string S (with words indexed from 0) and a substring Q. I wish to find the smallest range [L, R] in S which contains all words in Q. There are no duplicate words in Q. How do I approach this ?

For example,

**Input:**
**S**: what about the lazy brown fox that jumped over the other brown one which lazy dog ate the food of the fox
**Q**: lazy brown dog

**Output:** [11,15]

My code:

```
S = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
Q = raw_input().strip().split(' ')

count = [0 for x in range(len(Q))]
smallest_index = [0 for x in range(len(Q))]
largest_index = [0 for x in range(len(Q))]

for i in range(len(S)):
    for j in range(len(Q)):
        if S[i] == Q[j]:
            count[j] += 1
            if count[j] <= 1:
                smallest_index[j] = i
                largest_index[j] = i
            if count[j] > 1:
                largest_index[j] = i

largest_index.sort()
print "[%d," % largest_index[0],
print "%d]" % largest_index[len(Q)-1]
```

Comment: show the code which you tried ?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: It's possible you got a downvote because you posted a broad question with no code. Your question is much better now, but you need to explain what's wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: My issue is with the time complexity. I am running two loops. What if S and Q are of large magnitude ? How can I make it more efficient.

Comment: Fair enough. Why are you collecting `smallest_index` values but never using them? But apart from that I don't think that your algorithm will always find the correct minimal solution. The minimal range _could_ be one that uses the largest indices, the smallest indices, or somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I've got a brute-force solution that _does_ find the minimal range, but it's not particularly efficient. I'll see what I can do to improve it before I post it.

Comment: Oh well. None of my experiments were successful. But I've posted my code anyway, it may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This code isn't particular efficient, but it does work correctly. Perhaps someone will devise a better way of processing the position information than using `product`. In the mean time you can use this code to test other algorithms against.

```
from itertools import product

def words_range(src, query):
    # Create a dict to store the word positions in src of each query word
    pos = {s: [] for s in query}
    for i, s in enumerate(src):
        if s in pos:
            pos[s].append(i)
    print(pos)

    # Find all the ranges that hold all the query word 
    ranges = ((min(t), max(t)) for t in product(*pos.values()))
    # Find the smallest range
    return min(ranges, key=lambda t:t[1] - t[0])

# Test

src = '''what about the lazy brown fox that jumped over the other
brown one which lazy dog ate the food of the fox'''.split()
for i, s in enumerate(src):
    print(i, s)

query = 'lazy brown dog'.split()
print(words_range(src, query))

query = 'the lazy brown fox'.split()
print(words_range(src, query))
```

**output**

```
0 what
1 about
2 the
3 lazy
4 brown
5 fox
6 that
7 jumped
8 over
9 the
10 other
11 brown
12 one
13 which
14 lazy
15 dog
16 ate
17 the
18 food
19 of
20 the
21 fox
{'lazy': [3, 14], 'brown': [4, 11], 'dog': [15]}
(11, 15)
{'the': [2, 9, 17, 20], 'lazy': [3, 14], 'brown': [4, 11], 'fox': [5, 21]}
(2, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly more efficient version of [PM 2Ring's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47260660/1222951), replacing the call to `product` with a loop:

```
from itertools import product

def words_range(src, query):
    query = set(query)

    # Create a dict to store the word positions in src of each query word
    pos = {s: [] for s in query}
    for i, s in enumerate(src):
        if s in pos:
            pos[s].append(i)

    # Find all the ranges that hold all the query word 
    # We'll iterate over the input string and keep track of
    # where each word appeared last
    last_pos = {}
    ranges = []
    for i, word in enumerate(src):
        if word in query:
            last_pos[word] = i
            if len(last_pos) == len(query):
                ranges.append( (min(last_pos.values()), i) )

    # Find the smallest range
    return min(ranges, key=lambda t:t[1] - t[0])
```

It's not quite linear time (because of the `min(last_pos.values())` in the loop), but it's a step in the right direction. There's probably a way to get rid of the `min` call (that I can't think of right now), which would make this linear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach based on @PM 2Ring answer:

```
S ='what about the lazy brown fox that jumped over the other brown one which lazy dog ate the food of the fox'
Q ='lazy brown dog'

import itertools
track={}

for index,value in enumerate(S.split()):

    if value in Q:
        if value not in track:
            track[value]=[index]
        else:
            track[value].append(index)


combination = [(min(item),max(item)) for item in itertools.product(*track.values())]


result=min([(i[1]-i[0],(i[0],i[1])) for i in combination if set(Q.split()).issubset(S.split()[i[0]:i[1]+1])])
print(result[1])
```

output:

```
(11, 15)
```